# How can I clear the content of my notebook in Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

The `Clear` command is for clearing definitions of symbols. Is there any built-in function to clear the work area of my Notebook?

Comment: Similar question here: [Command to clean screen in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847815/is-there-any-command-or-routine-to-clean-screen-in-mathematica).

Comment: Have you tried Select All from the Edit menu, followed by the Delete key? Shortcut for the menu command is Cmnd + A on OS X (Ctrl +A on other platforms?)

Answer (score 9):

This will delete everything in the evaluation Notebook:

```
NotebookDelete[Cells[]]
```

This will generate a [Palette](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Palettes.html) [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) that deletes everything is the selected Notebook:

```
CreatePalette @ Button["Clear Notebook", NotebookDelete @ Cells @ InputNotebook[]]
```

As noted in the comments it is probably just as fast, if not faster, to simply Select All and Clear (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> in Windows).

Answer (score 4):

This is very efficient for large Notebooks:

```
NotebookPut[Notebook[{}], EvaluationNotebook[]];
```

(simple replacement of the evaluation notebook with blank notebook).

I have tested this method with a Notebook of size 976 Mb containing 36031 `Cell`s and it was cleared out in no time, while the [`NotebookDelete[Cells[]]` method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89881/280) seems to take forever for this Notebook!

Comment: A caution: this is *not* undoable, whereas `NotebookDelete` is at least so far as the Front End remembers.  +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Just a question....how did you manage to create 976MB of rubbish spread out in 36031 cells? :-)

Comment: @magma I don't think your joke makes sense (but don't delete your comment please!). I have experience with very large MMa files containing the results of work which was in progress during several years. Sometimes it is convenient to work with a single Notebook over the years even when it becomes huge.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Relax, it was just a friendly joke (see the smiley). It does not have to make sense. Actually jokes are often funnier if they challenge common sense.  I have great respect for your MMA knowledge. I just giggled at the thought of someone painstakingly building a huge notebook, counting its cells one by one and then...erasing it. To be honest though, perhaps I am missing the point of this 3d. If I have a nb I am not happy with, I salvage what is worth saving in another nb and then simply delete the bad nb from the file system. what is the point of erasing/overwriting a whole nb?

Comment: @magma From the original question I imagine someone who work with MMa as with a blackboard. Of course in this case the Notebook will not contain many `Cell`s and the `NotebookDelete[Cells[]]` method is more appropriate. But who knows, there may be other use cases where speed is critical and UNDO isn't needed. It is always good to have an alternative. By the way, now it's your joke seems funny to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean screen, then ctrl + A to select all cells and then hit del. If you mean memory, then `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` if it does not help, restart...